# Angular 2 karma setup issue -- Karma starts but doesn't run tests

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

In brief,

- I'm creating a project starting with the Plunker code for the Angular
  2 "Routing" example (access through [the Angular 2 Advanced Tutorial
  for Routing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) link). That source doesn't have the Karma or Jasmine
  configuration baked in.
- I've been trying unsatisfactorily to add this to the existing
  project.  My current setup runs karma but doesn't see any tests, either .js or .ts.

> ```
> 14 01 2017 19:16:44.080:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
> 14 01 2017 19:16:44.112:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.4.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
> 14 01 2017 19:16:44.112:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
> 14 01 2017 19:16:44.268:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
> 14 01 2017 19:16:46.895:INFO [Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket [SNIP]
> ```

First I started with the [the Angular 2 Advanced Tutorial for Testing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html) link.  That says I should create /app/1st.spec.ts:

```
describe('lst tests', () => {
    it('true is true', () => expect(false).toBe(true));
});
```

I then ran npm test, but found I had no Karma capability.  Since then I've installed a variety of packages, based on  [advice from a programmer's blog](http://www.portfour.com/2016/08/24/jasmine-and-karma-for-angular-unit-testing/).  My installations have become:

```
npm install karma –save-dev
npm install karma-jasmine jasmine-core –save-dev
npm install karma-chrome-launcher –save-dev 
npm install karma-cli
npm install angular-mocks
npm install requirejs karma-requirejs
```

I ran "karma init" and answered questions best I could. My current karma.conf.js is (condensed):

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      {pattern: 'app/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'app/*.spec.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'app/**/*.js', included: false}
    ],
    exclude: [ ],
    preprocessors: { },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "MyProgram",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "MyProgram description",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "gulp copy-jit && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
      "lite": "lite-server",
      "tsc": "tsc",
      "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
      "aot": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
      "rollup": "rollup -c rollup-config.js",
      "start-aot": "npm run aot && npm run rollup && gulp copy-aot && npm run lite",
      "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.4",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.32",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-gzip": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-task-listing": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "rollup": "^0.36.1",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^5.0.4",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

The things I hope to resolve through your responses are:

- A proper Angular 2 project configuration for Karma and Jasmine
  testing.
- The ability to create Typescript source code tests and have them detected and run in Karma.

Thanks,

Jerome.

Comment: Here's a [good article](https://psamsotha.github.io/angular/2016/12/16/angular2-testing-karma-systemjs.html).

Comment: Your link is very good.  It explores karma and its various configurations.  It also seems -- from the article, from other posters and by my experiences -- that I really must go back to the Quickstart.  At this state of Angular 2 maturity there isn't a well-defined way of diagnosing an installation.  I should just recreate the project -- or delete node_modules and reinstall.  Once I did load Quickstart on my PC I saw lots of little bits that I wasn't going to resolve myself through tinkering.

Comment: I used the Angular Quickstart to get a "fresh" version of the environment.  My libraries translated roughly from version 2.2.4 to 2.4.  I copied my code into the new environment.  Behold!  Things don't work!  It seems that developers changed the signature of the Resolve interface.  Fortunately the Routing tutorial was also updated, so I had an easy fix.  But I thought that with a "greater than Beta" version that interfaces were going to be immutable.  /rant

Answer (score 0):

- I too was trying to go thru the process. I know that if you do **ng new** using the Angular CLI it will create a project for you with all the Karma stuff setup correctly.
- **ng test** is similar to **npm test** but seems to spin up far faster too.
- The package.json "scripts" section controls the "test" command line option.
- I attempted to copy it into the Tour Of Heroes part 6 and managed to successfully do the 1st.spec.ts and get Karma to launch and flip true = true to true = false.
- But at the point it said you could load up 1st.spec.ts in Chrome things wouldn't work for me either (Point 5 [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-debugging)).
- I documented the way to copy files across [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779294/angular-router-example-best-way-to-upgrade-to-include-angular-cli-json-and-bypa/44810864#44810864).
- You also have the added nuisance that Karma used a version of Node that is behind the times using the LTS release cycle. So it's wise to setup nvm. See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3554#issuecomment-311488799)