# Angular Router example Best way to upgrade to include .angular-cli.json and bypass Cannot read property 'config' of null

Tags: angular2-routing, angular-cli

I tried downloading the Routing and Navigation example from this [page](https://angular.io/guide/router#overview)

Here's the link to the specific [zip](https://angular.io/generated/zips/router/router.zip).

I run the following sequence of commands:

1. **npm install**
2. **npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest**
3. **ng -v**
4. **ng serve -o**

From what I can make out **Cannot read property 'config' of null**
is somehow related to a bad version of the CLI. But if I create a new project I can start it successfully with my existing setup

1. **ng new router**
2. **cd router**
3. **npm install**
4. **ng serve -o**

Old directory structure (from zip download) includes these files:

- bs-config.json
- e2e-spec.ts

New directory structure (from ng new):

- .angular-cli.json
- e2e is a folder with files inside
- karma.conf.js
- protractor.conf.js
- tsconfig.json

**Is there some sort of ng upgrade command to convert a project?**
There was some talk on [Git about **ng init**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/755), but that seems to now be a thing of the past.
I believe most of the files are related to end to end testing.

```
    npm install
    npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
    npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead

    > phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.14 install /opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
    > node install.js

    PhantomJS not found on PATH
    Download already available at /var/folders/xz/sgpc803n1ms6xpc5n571ytc80000gn/T/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip
    Verified checksum of previously downloaded file
    Extracting zip contents
    Removing /opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
    Copying extracted folder /var/folders/xz/sgpc803n1ms6xpc5n571ytc80000gn/T/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip-extract-1498561599287/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx -> /opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
    Writing location.js file
    Done. Phantomjs binary available at /opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

    > fsevents@1.1.2 install /opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/fsevents
    > node install

    [fsevents] Success: "/opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
    Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile
    npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
    added 767 packages in 20.239s


    ng serve -o
    Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.

    Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
    "npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest" 

    You have to be inside an Angular CLI project in order to use the serve command.
    /opt/AngularProjects/router>


    npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
    npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.2 should be installed with -g

    > node-sass@4.5.3 install /opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/node-sass
    > node scripts/install.js

    Cached binary found at /Users/jgf/.npm/node-sass/4.5.3/darwin-x64-57_binding.node

    > node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall /opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/node-sass
    > node scripts/build.js

    Binary found at /opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57/binding.node
    Testing binary
    Binary is fine
    + @angular/cli@1.1.3
    added 431 packages in 17.132s

    ==
    ng -v
        _                      _                 ____ _     ___
       / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
      / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
     / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
    /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                   |___/
    @angular/cli: 1.1.3
    node: 8.1.2
    os: darwin x64
    @angular/animations: 4.2.4
    @angular/common: 4.2.4
    @angular/compiler: 4.2.4
    @angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.4
    @angular/core: 4.2.4
    @angular/forms: 4.2.4
    @angular/http: 4.2.4
    @angular/platform-browser: 4.2.4
    @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.4
    @angular/platform-server: 4.2.4
    @angular/router: 4.2.4
    @angular/tsc-wrapped: 4.2.4
    @angular/upgrade: 4.2.4
    @angular/cli: 1.1.3


    ng serve -o
    Cannot read property 'config' of null
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
        at Class.run (/opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:22:63)
        at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:110:26)
        at 
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

In relation to the error in:
/opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js
we have:

```
const config_1 = require("../models/config");
...
const projectConfig = config_1.CliConfig.fromProject().config;
```

I suspect this pertains to a missing **.angular-cli.json** file.
/opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.d.ts
and
/opt/AngularProjects/router/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js
refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

That project (the one in the zip file) is not setup as a CLI-based project. But after opening it up, you can get it running by doing the following:

- npm install
- npm run start

This will open your default browser to http://localhost:3000/ where the app will be running.

NOTE: you'll also want to undo any changes you've made (or unzip again)

Comment: Ah ok. Just deleting the node_modules folder  and running those commands did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Glad that worked for you, please mark this as the accepted answer so others can easily find it.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the project to a CLI one, by following these steps, so I could run **ng test** and follow along with the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip) project and run karma tests etc based on [testing documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-first-karma-test):

1. Create a blank new project with ng new <project name>
2. Delete node_modules folder, then copied the following over into existing project:
3. .angular-cli.json
   renaming "name:" key to same value of "name:" in package.json
4. e2e folder containing:

   - app.e2e-spec.ts
   - app.po.ts
   - tsconfig.e2e.json
5. karma.conf.js
6. protractor.conf.js
7. tsconfig.json (rename original to tsconfig.orig.json if necessary)
8. tslint.json (rename original to tsconfig.orig.json if necessary)
9. copy package.json to package.orig.json. Then in package.json...:

   - updated scripts: updating/adding:

     - "ng": "ng",
     - "build": "ng build",
     - "start": "ng serve",
     - "e2e": "ng e2e",
     - "test": "ng test",
     - "lint": "ng lint"
   - dependencies:

     - updated all @angular using modules
     - npm install @angular/<package-name>@latest --save
       i.e.: (prefaced with @angular/) animations,common, compiler, core, forms, http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router.
   - devDependencies:

     - npm install @angular/<package-name>@latest --save-dev
       @angular/cli, @angular/compiler-cli, @angular/language-service
   - I also included in devDependencies:

     - "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
     - "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
     - "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
     - "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
     - "karma": "^1.7.0",
     - "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
     - "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
     - "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
     - "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
     - "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
     - "protractor": "~5.1.2",
     - "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
     - "tslint": "^5.3.1",
     - "typescript": "~2.3.3"
10. In src folder copied:

    - assets/.gitkeep
    - environments/environment.prod.ts
    - environments/environment.ts
    - polyfills.ts
    - test.ts
    - tsconfig.app.json
    - tsconfig.spec.json
    - typings.d.ts
11. Replaced main.ts (In my case it added extra production env stuff)
12. In src folder:

    - renamed tsconfig.json tsconfig.orig.json (I was able to rely on tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json)

      You may need to tweak index.html. I did not..
13. run npm install
14. run ng serve -o
15. run ng test

**Voila!**

Note: If you get this error when running ng test:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15457:109)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15389:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15338:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15192:29)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.getSourceFile (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/compiler_host.js:210:27)
    at findSourceFile (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67909:29)
    at processSourceFile (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67840:27)
    at processRootFile (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67728:13)
    at /opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67018:60
    at Object.forEach (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1449:30)
    at Object.createProgram (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67018:16)
    at AotPlugin._setupOptions (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:129:28)
    at new AotPlugin (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:26:14)
    at _createAotPlugin (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:55:12)
    at Object.exports.getNonAotTestConfig (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:102:19)
    at WebpackTestConfig.buildConfig (/opt/AngularProjects/quickstart/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-test-config.js:16:31)
```

it's because you've missed an required item. For me it was **test.ts**. See [here](https://github.com/Urigo/Ionic2CLI-Meteor-WhatsApp/issues/82#issuecomment-311742154).