# Angular 2 Testing with Karma/Jasmine : Enable view of spec.ts files in Chrome

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

Does anyone if there is a more detailed blog post or video review dissecting the makeup of the configuration of the project that gets talked about in the [The first karma test](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-first-karma-test) ([1st-specs.testing.zip](https://angular.io/generated/zips/testing/1st-specs.testing.zip))?

I say this because if you setup an Angular project normally with **ng new** it sets up karma so you can run **ng test**, instead of the scripted **npm test** configured in the package.json of 1st-specs.testing.zip.

1st-specs.testing.zip is much better than ng test though, because it allows you to **view spec.ts files and even set breakpoints on the test scripts and halt execution to interrogate things in the Chrome browser**.

There is an awful lot of configuration going on in that example that I'm currently struggling to get my head around. I don't know specifically what part enables viewing the spec.ts files in Chrome.

Does anyone know:

- what part enables that functionality, or
- who wrote that code, so I could perhaps go Google their blog?

Nicer still, would be having this functionality baked into a project created by ng new!

Comment: Your problem has been addressed and is being fixed: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6892. I'd suggest you apply the changes yourself or wait for the next release and continue using the CLI, because it's a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see your spec files in chrome and debug it, when karma launches your browser, click on `DEBUG`, in the new tab open the chrome console (F12), go to the `Sources` tab, hit `Ctrl+P` and type in your file name.

It will open the file and allow you to put a breakpoint in it.

**EDIT** Proof :

[image: karma_debug]

Comment: But the .spec.ts will not be available if you use ng new to set up a project. Instead you get something like an amalgamated webpack file iirc. The spec file will not be able to be selected. It's all tied in to the configuration somehow.

Comment: If you mean you can't open it in the console, it's false, you can. I don't know what you mean otherwise, but I use this method everyday to test my project and it works like a charm.

Comment: See my edit, and see that it's possible (and yes, I'm using angular CLI)

Comment: I think this must be something of my own doing then. Because I merged an ng new project with an existing project and must have messed the configuration up somehow. Because I can't see the spec.ts files. I'll have to dig deeper into what I did wrong. This basically was what I did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779294/angular-router-example-best-way-to-upgrade-to-include-angular-cli-json-and-bypa/44781902?noredirect=1#comment76546306_44781902

Comment: Yup, it's on you, sorry !

Comment: I also cannot select the source files in chrome. Used Angular CLI 1.2.0 on macOS. My test is run but the source is not available :(

Comment: Did you do what I said ?

Comment: @trichetriche yes

Comment: Sorry I don't trust you (it's not personal though), could do it again and describe every step in a comment ? Maybe you missed something ans I could point it out to you

Comment: @trichetriche no

Comment: @trichetriche The problem is not how to use the Chrome tools to debug. With the current Angular CLI (1.2.0) the created project includes *.spec.ts files via test.js and not via karma.conf.js anymore. The tests are run in the browser and you see the results. But you cannot select the files for setting breakpoints etc. So your steps are irrelevant to reproduce the problem. Maybe we shouldn't trust you that you are using the current CLI? (no offense!).

Comment: You're actually right, I just tested it and it doesn't work anymore. But it took me literally 10 seconds to find another way : all the tests are in main.bundle.js. Just open the file and type your `it` description, and you're ready to debug.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been addressed and a fix is on the way. If you apply the changes yourself, it will work again with the current CLI generated project:
[fix(@angular/cli): use inline sourcemaps in test](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/6862)

[image]